# How to make conditional interface base on props in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

what is the best way to implement conditional props, i having something like this, a component that would be a view or a button that base on a props, which i call here `CountdownButtonI`
It look like this

```
class CountDownButton extends Component<CountdownButtonI> {
  constructor(props:CountdownButtonI) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { t, title, onPress, time } = this.props;

    return time ? (
      <View style={{ ...Layout.flexView }}>
        <Label text={t('common.countdown.otpCountdown')} style={{ ...LabelStyle.SubBodyText, color: Colors.black }} />
        <Label
          text={moment.utc(time * 1000).format('HH:mm:ss')}
          style={{ ...LabelStyle.SubBodyTextMedium, fontWeight: '500', color: Colors.black }}
        />
      </View>
    ) : (
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={onPress}>
        <Label text={title} style={{ ...LabelStyle.BodyTextMedium, color: Colors.white }} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

For CountdownButtonI i set like this

```
interface CountdownButtonI{
  t: any;
  title: any;
  time: any;
}
```

But i feel it not optimal at all, like, when i have `time` props, `onPress` still visible, how can i avoid this, like, if i have `time` props, the `onPress` will raise an error

Comment: Consider [this](https://tsplay.dev/wE42VW)

Comment: ALso, you can consider using [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions). For more information you can also check my [article](https://catchts.com/unions)

Comment: First of all, thank @captain-yossarianfromUkraine, but do we other way? I found it a little bit complex

Comment: It seems like these are two very different components.  **None** of the props are the same and none of the rendering is the same either!  Is there any reason that you don't just separate them?  `CountDownButton` with `onPress` and `title` and `CountDownTimer` with `time` (and `t` from i18next).

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions).

```js
import React from 'react'

interface WithTime {
  withTime: true
  t: (val: string) => string;
  time: number;
}

interface WithTitle {
  withTime: false
  title: string;
  onPress: () => void
}


type Props = WithTime | WithTitle


const render = (props: Props) => {
  const { withTime } = props;

  if (withTime) {
    const { t, time } = props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{time}</p>
        <p>{t('hello')}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }

  const { title, onPress } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <button onClick={onPress}>click</button>
    </div>
  )

}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NB4ddW)

`withTime` property is a discriminator. It exists in each union and has different values.

Answer (score 1):

@captain-yossarian has given you a good answer to the question that you are asking, but IMO you are asking the wrong questions.

There is no reason that your two situations (the view and the button) should be the same component.  They do not share any props, any logic, any UI, or even any styles.

You are adding a level of complexity that simply does not need to be there.

Do yourself a favor and make this into two separate components.  Each component will only accept the props which make sense for that specific case.

```
interface CountDownButtonProps {
  onPress: () => void; // or (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void
  title: string;
}

export const CountDownButton = ({ onPress, title }: CountDownButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={onPress}>
      <Label text={title} style={{ ...LabelStyle.BodyTextMedium, color: Colors.white }} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

```
interface CountDownTimerProps {
  time: number;
}

export const CountDownTimer = ({ time }: CountDownTimerProps) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <View style={{ ...Layout.flexView }}>
      <Label
        text={t('common.countdown.otpCountdown')}
        style={{ ...LabelStyle.SubBodyText, color: Colors.black }}
      />
      <Label
        text={moment.utc(time * 1000).format('HH:mm:ss')}
        style={{ ...LabelStyle.SubBodyTextMedium, fontWeight: '500', color: Colors.black }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```